# Handling of exponential number through JavaScript VS C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, extjs

I have a exponential number : `4.65661287307739E-10`

When I round it off using JavaScript, it gets converted as 5. I use following code

```
  var roundFormattedNumber = function (n) {
                    var val = parseFloat(n.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')).toFixed(0);
                    Ext.util.Format.thousandSeparator = ',';
                    Ext.util.Format.decimalSeparator = '.';
                    return Ext.util.Format.number(val, '0,000');
                };
```

When I try to first parse this number into decimal using C# I get : `0.000000000465661287307739M`

```
decimal amount;
decimal.TryParse("4.65661287307739E-10", NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out amount);
```

If I round off this value using C# result would be different as compared to JavaScript result.

**Why there is a difference? Which result it correct?**

Please suggest.

Thank you

Comment: FYI `4.65661287307739E-10 == 0.000000000465661287307739`; expecting that it would round to _5.0_ is silly.

Comment: @SalmanA : Thank you for quick reply. I see the error now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I round it off using JavaScript, it gets converted as 5.

That's not JavaScript, that's your code. You're removing everything from the string that isn't a digit or a `.`:

```
var val = parseFloat(n.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')).toFixed(0);
// -------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

...so you're turning

```
4.65661287307739E-10
```

into

```
4.6566128730773910
```

and then parsing that, which naturally gives you a completely different number from `4.65661287307739E-10`. There's no need to do that, JavaScript's `parseFloat` can interpret E-notation.

Whereas in your C# code, you're actually providing the E-notation number to the `TryParse` function.

> Why there is a difference?

Because in the one case you're removing *really important information* from the string before asking JavaScript to parse it.

> Which result it correct?

The C# one (although I have no idea why there's an `M` at the end of it).